# Fractional exponent POWER function error ("An invalid floating point operation occurred.")

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 sales_3Y
 0.521
 1.282
 0.71
 1.513
 1.502
 2357
 1.291
 1.393
 0
 0
 2.009
```

I need to calculate the 1/nth root of the column.

```
Select POWER(sales_3YR,(1.0/3))
```

> Error - An invalid floating point operation occurred.

Comment: presumably you have negative sales somehow in a row.

Comment: For the data you have provided, it doesn't produce the error you say it does: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5614212d497939dd711771009a34c98). But, as @MartinSmith presumed, if you have a negative number, it does: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f8345997f6ba90d8b370059f336ab85)

Comment: The examples in your question all work:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87b99799a429792b28d982cfe9933153.

Answer (score 2):

This suggests that `POWER(x,n)` for fractional n is implemented internally as `exp(n*log(x))`, which would fail for all `x<0`.  You can work around it for the special cases of an odd n-th root with a user-defined function like:

```
create or alter function dbo.CubeRoot(@x float)
returns float
as
begin
  if @x = 0 return 0;

  return sign(@x) * exp(log(abs(@x))/3.0)
end
```

and

```
select dbo.CubeRoot(-8)
```

outputs

```
-2
```

Comment: The error doesn't really suggest anything about the implementation (although your approach is likely how it is implemented).  Roots of negative numbers go into the realm of imaginary numbers, which SQL Server does not provide native support for.  The problem is that 1/3.0 might work.  But 0.333333333333333 does not.

Comment: Point is that it's not implemented by performing the operation in the complex plane, and picking a real-valued solution, ie one with a sufficiently small imaginary component.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks a lot